# Row numbering selection auto-fill till the end

Tags: excel, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I have a table with thousands of lines. I want to number rows by adding 1 2 3 next to first rows, then to select these and drag till end to make a fill with increasing numbers.

How to autofill till last row without dragging with a mouse for several minutes?

Comment: This question is suited to SuperUser, not SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you know how to double-click the autofill handle? If you put 1,2 in the first two cells, then select both cells and double-click the little black box in the bottom right corner, it should "automagically" do what you are asking. It will fill for as many rows as there are filled cells adjacent to it. Quite a handy trick.

For example, see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-HP001216366.aspx

> Tips You can also fill the active cell with the formula of an adjacent
>   cell by using the Fill command (on the Home tab in the Editing group)
>   or by pressing CTRL+D to fill a cell below or CTRL+R to fill a cell to
>   the right of the cell containing the formula. You can automatically
>   fill a formula downward, for all adjacent cells that it applies to, by
>   double-clicking the fill handle of the first cell that contains the
>   formula. For example, cells A1:A15 and B1:B15 contain numbers, and you
>   type the formula =A1+B1 in cell C1. To copy that formula into cells
>   C2:C15, select cell C1 and double-click the fill handle.

Comment: A double-click, omg! :D Sometimes obvious is hardest to find!