# Making formula work for entire column in one shot in Excel

Tags: excel

I am new to Excel, This is how my spreadsheet looks

```
      A          B          C  
1   income1   income2    Total_Income
2    1000      3000      =A2+B2
3    2000      4000
4    3000      5000
5    4000      1000
6    5000      2000
.      .         .
.      .         .
.      .         .
5000  8000     3000
```

say I have 5000 rows in my spreadsheet and I want to make the formula work for the entire 5000 rows in one shot. How do I do that?

I tried with Cntrl + Shift + Down arrow  and cntrl + D but it leads to the end of the file i.e row number 1048574.

How do I select only 5000 rows i.e the total number of rows in my spreadsheet and make the formula work in one shot without dragging.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following URL, it has already been answered on StackOverFlow

[Row numbering selection auto-fill till the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086069/row-numbering-selection-auto-fill-till-the-end)

Check the above link and hope this will help you.